# Does Jurassic Park: Operation Genesis run better on Xbox 360 or the Xbox?

Tags: xbox-360, performance, xbox, jurassic-park-operation-genesis

I just bought Jurassic Park: Operation Genesis for my original Xbox, but it runs very slowly.

If I were to buy an Xbox 360 and download the game on it, will it run better than it does on the original Xbox?